# Variable from python disappears giving error in syntax

Tags: javascript, python, session

I have this piece of code in my **index.htm**l:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var session_cookie_age_html = {{ session_cookie_age }};
        var user_logged_html = {{ user_logged }};

        if (session_cookie_age_html.length !== 0 && user_logged_html.length !== 0){

            var MyGlobalVars = {
                SESSION_COOKIE_AGE_JS: session_cookie_age_html,
                user_logged_js : user_logged_html,
            };
        }else{

            var MyGlobalVars = {}   
        }

    </script>
```

I get *session_cookie_age* from my settings.

When *session_cookie_age* doesn't existe it will leave the code like this:

```
var session_cookie_age_html = ;
```

Which obviously gives an error. There's no way of asking if the variable is undefined as it doesn't even exist, this is really weird. Is there a way I can check if the variable exists or something?

Comment: Is it throwing error in console on assignment line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        {% if session_cookie_age %}

            //your code

        {% endif %}

</script>
```